# Perforce to BitBucket migration

Tags: git, bitbucket, perforce

Not sure if I'm approaching this from the right angle, but here's how I need to migrate a project from perforce to bitbucket. I have very little experience with Git.

I'm not interested in preserving the commit history, just the structure of repos and branches. Since the code is already locally it should basically be sent bitbucket.

Say I have in P4:

```
   PROJECT repository:
      project_component_A_dir
          main branch
          branch-1
          branch-2
      project_component_B_dir
          main branch
          branch-1
          branch-2
```

I need to migrate it in BitBucket:

```
PROJECT
   repo_project_component_A
      master
      branch-1
      branch-2
   repo_project_component_B
      master
      branch-1
      branch-2
```

The way I try to achieve is :

```
   cd ../project_component_A_dir/main_branch
   git init
   git add *
   git commit -m 'commiting the master'
   git remote add origin https://repo_project_component_A
   git push -u origin master

  cd ../project_component_A_dir/branch-1
  git checkout -b branch-1, but the result is an error
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, and even less if this is the right way to do it. I'd like to have some feedback about this and to hear about other strategies in achieving the above descriebed.

Thank you